# SOLR - Use Aggregate functions in Grouping

Tags: sql, solr

I have a set of data in which i have different products named A, B, C and D and there are multiple entries of A, B, C, D differentiating based on denomination value. Each product has its own item_score. I need to group the data based on title A,B,C and D and sort them based on item_score.

I tried using `group=true&group.field=title&group.main=true` and `sort=itemScore+desc`. This gave me some result but when I did sort=itemScore+asc then the itemScore of each A,B,C,D changed, but practically it should not, only order of A, B, C, D should change.

Is there any way in Solr to accomplish this?

Example

```
Title A Deno. 50 ItemScore 2
Title A Deno. 100 ItemScore 4
Title B Deno 10 ItemScore 1
Title C Deno 100 ItemScore 3
Title C Deno 1000 ItemScore 5
Title D Deno 10 ItemScore 1
```

Expected Output: (item score sort desc)

```
Title C ItemScore 4
Title A ItemScore 3
Title B ItemScore 1
Title D ItemScore 1
```

and on sort asc

```
Title B ItemScore 1
Title D ItemScore 1
Title A ItemScore 3
Title C ItemScore 4
```

Actual Output( sort desc)

```
Title C ItemScore 5
Title A ItemScore 4
Title B ItemScore 1
Title D ItemScore 1
```

sort asc

```
Title B ItemScore 1
Title D ItemScore 1
Title A ItemScore 2
Title C ItemScore 3
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're saying? It's a bit difficult to understand from your question what issue you're facing.

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: You've put up the expected output but what output are you seeing which according to you is incorrect?